# OnLongClick textview to edit

Tags: android, textview

I've been search SO for quite a while, but I haven't found what I'm looking for. I want to let the user to be able to do onLongClick on my textview, and when it is onlongclick, it should appear as an inline editing. And so the user can change the data from the textview and can save the changes. So far this is what I've tried:

```
     tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imm.showSoftInput(userInput, 0);
    return true;
}
```

But I don't have an idea how to actually do the inline editing. Do you have any ideas to do that? I badly need to do this thing. Help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom dialog with EditText in it and open this dialog dialog in your Long ClickListener , Get the text from your EditText(Dialog) and update the same in your TextView after user press Ok button of Dialog.

This is a **code snippet** for you

```
final TextView result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);



    result.setOnLongClickListener(
            new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // get prompts.xml view
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(Demo.this);
                    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Demo.this);

                    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            // get user input and set it to
                                            // result
                                            // edit text
                                            result.setText(userInput
                                                    .getText());
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

**prompts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit you Text : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Added Layout for dialog too , enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you dude I try to incorporate this to my current project.

Answer (score 2):

You may want a stylised a non editable EditText, which you make editable and focused when it is longClicked.

Answer (score 2):

Make a ***non Editable editText*** (and display any message in it if you want), attach longClickListener to the EditText and when long press occurs, ***make it editable***.

Comment: I mentioned already that when **long press occurs, make the EditText Editable** and when the user has provided the input, store in DB

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a hidden editText and when textView long clicked, hide the textview and show hidden edittext. After finish editting, hide the edittext and show the textView again.

Comment: okay I have created, can you give me snippets of code to get started with?